# WPF window maximizing fully

Tags: wpf, window, maximize-window

I've a custom WPF window and i implemented code when i click on title bar it maximizes full area without task bar that is OK, but when i pressed the left mouse button on title bar and move towards top then my window maximizes entire screen including task bar but i want to maximize with exemption of task bar, so please any one help me to get out of this.

Thanks,
@nagaraju.

Answer (score 0):

This solution may help you :) get the position of the taskbar(Fixed Position) and set the taskbar position to the fixed one on the windows sizechange event

```
    private double positionX;//set this value to the value of the fixed taskbar X position
    private double positionY;//set this value to the value of the fixed taskbar Y position

    private void Window_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        label1.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, positionY);
        label1.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, positionX);
    }
```